# django - HttpResponse for already full

Tags: python, django, http, django-rest-framework

I have a **django** server and a **view** that is called when the user tries to add himself to a bus.

If the bus is already full, I want to return a HttpResponse with status code "already full" - or something like that, and add a description saying the bus is already full.

again, the server is in django and I am working with django rest framework.

what would you suggest?

Comment: Have you looked the definitions of the existing HTTP status codes? If so, extend your question on what you did consider already and why it was not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You should raise a custom exception for full busses

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException

class FullBusException(APIException):
    status_code = 409
    default_detail = 'This bus is already full.'
```

Then in your view code import and raise this exception if the bus is already full when the user tries to add themselves to it. Django rest framework will then deal with handling the exception.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/

Comment: Looks more like HTTP status code `503` (Service Unavailable) to me.

Comment: Thanks for your anseer. And in the view just raise FullBusException?  Or return?

Comment: @OfekAgmon you would raise the exception rather than return.

Comment: Thanks!  So the django rest framework returns the response?  (according to the raised exception)?